# UNLocationNotificationTrigger not firing on device in background

Tags: ios, notifications, location, local, unusernotificationcenter

I am building an app that uses local notifications that are location sensitive. I would like these to trigger even when the app is in background. I was able to get this to work in simulator, but not device. They fire on device but only in foreground.

Here is how I am setting up:

```
        let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region:region, repeats:true)
        let delete = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "DeleteAction",
                                                title: "Delete", options: [.destructive])
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: “testcategory”, actions: [delete], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        center.setNotificationCategories([category])
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = “This is a test“
        content.body = "You're at your destination"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.categoryIdentifier = “testcategory”
        let identifier = "testnotif"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    //successful
                }
            })
```

Comment: could you edit your question to show a bit of code?  For example, where you create your `UNLocationNotificationTrigger` object?

Comment: Updated with code for how I am setting up. I am also using "always" scope for location updates

Comment: try adding an UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger first to make sure your app can fire notifications.